# Downloading or caching web based map service for faster access?

Tags: web-mapping, performance, australia

The Western Australia Department of Mine and Petroleum allows access to one of their online systems called [Tengraph Web](http://www.dmp.wa.gov.au/TENGRAPH-Web-21427.aspx) with which I can view tenements, major infrastructure, and topography for the state of Western Australia. There is an option to overlay "Landgate Aerial Imagery" which is basically a satellite view of the same area however none of the areas I scroll over are cached thus every time I move my window, the aerial view has to load it again. With poor Australian internet, I was wondering if anyone had ideas as to either download or cache the aerial view data so I can navigate more easily without having to wait a few minutes for every kilometre of land to load.

Comment: Careful, their ToS probably do not allow this.

Comment: When you use a pre-made online map tool, you're limited to the built-in features. If they didn't build in an off-line or cached mapping option, you can't create it yourself. If they allow you to download the layers of interest, you can load them into a GIS program on your own computer and use them locally.

Answer (score 2):

As your question title suggests you need to set up a local cache, there are various solutions to this. I have in used both [GeoServer](https://geoserver.org) and [MapProxy](https://mapproxy.org) to solve similar problems.

In both cases you can create a pass through proxy that takes tile (WMTS) requests from the client and checks the local cache and if the tile is not present fetches the tile from the remote server.

I gave a [talk](https://www.ianturton.com/talks/pirates-foss4g/index.html#/step-1) (or [video](https://vimeo.com/248676799)) on setting up a system like this using a Raspberry Pi at FOSS4G a few years ago.

Comment: I found this answer very interesting and relative to my problem but I had a few problems executing it in that I don't know how a Raspberry Pi works and it seemed that some of the software required Python (?). I'm only working on my own out in the field so it would only be necessary on my personal laptop. Would there be any way for me to contact you to discuss this further?